# Java GUI FullScreen window with smaller window inside

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am working on a Java desktop application. It uses MySQL database to store all data etc. I use swing for the GUI.

The GUI of this application is layed out as follows:

1. Main Window taking the entire screen size (with image in the
   background)
2. Internal Window 800 x 600 centered within the Main
   Window (that holds current content that can be switched between
   using menu and/or event within the application.

LoginPanel.java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class LoginPanel {

    private JPanel loginPanel;

    public void loginForm()
    {
        JButton loginSubmit = new JButton("Login");

        loginPanel = new JPanel();
        loginPanel.add(loginSubmit);
        loginPanel.setSize(800, 600);
    }

    public JComponent getGUI() 
    {
        return loginPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    }


}
```

Main.java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame mainFrame;
        mainFrame = new JFrame();
        mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setTitle("Caledonian Library System");     
        LoginPanel loginObj = new LoginPanel();
        mainFrame.add(loginObj.getGUI());
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);      
    }

}
```

Should I maybe use box layout? any suggestions?

Comment: When you say internal window, does it  require the close, minimise, etc buttons, like a JFrame, or is it simply a panel you would like placed in the centre of  mainFrame?

Comment: A panel without borders close, minimize etc buttons. But it has to be able to change content. For example Login Panel, Register Panel and many diffrent panels after login.

Comment: Sounds like you need a [CardLayout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) for the internal window.  You're going about designing the GUI backwards.  You create the different panels and let the Swing layout managers determine the size of the card layout panel.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc I think you may have added the wrong link there. Try this one for [Card Layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: @Stevo: Sometimes, copy and paste doesn't copy.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have just run a test program, and have achieved the result you are looking for. I have used a GridBagLayout which defaults to centre into the Container it is added to. It will not show up with the borders or other buttons built into a JFrame (though you can add a border if you wish later).

```
JFrame mainframe = new JFrame();
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
GridBagLayout gridLayout = new GridBagLayout();
mainPanel.setLayout(gridLayout);

//GridBagConstraints allow you to set various features of the way the components appear
//in the grid. You can set this up as you wish, but defaults are fine for this example
GridBagConstraints gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();

//Just using FlowLayout as a test for now
JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
centerPanel.add(new JLabel("Hello"));
centerPanel.add(new JLabel("Centered"));

mainPanel.add(centerPanel, gridConstraints);

mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
```

If you found that the space around the side of your centered panel wasn't being used, and you wanted it to be use, you could try nesting mainPanel inside another panel that is using a BorderLayout, making sure that it is in BorderLayout.CENTER.

In the example I didn't bother changing GridBagConstraints from the default, as it was ok for this demonstration. However you can edit it as you wish, and then apply to each component you add to the GridBagLayout, making sure to include the GridBagConstraints object in each mainPanel.add(). Check the [GridBagLayout tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for some good information.

Of course, if you would like more components in the centre other than the main window, you can then simply add them to the mainPanel (making sure to change the position in the GridLayout). There are going to be numerous ways of achieving what you want, but it really depends on what you feel looks good. The Layout Managers will do all of the resizing work for you.

Comment: What's c in mainPanel.add(centerPanel, c); ? It displays error for me

Comment: Oh sorry, that is meant to be gridConstraints. I'll edit now, thanks for that.